# Where can I find the facebook php class reference?

Tags: php, class, facebook

For an example, there is a set_user function

$facebook->set_user

but I typed in set_user at the facebook developer wiki search box, it returns 
'There is no page titled "set_user"'

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Special:Search?search=set_user&go=Go

Where can I find the list of the functions and properties for the facebook object user object etc?

Many thanks.

Comment: Facebook documentation is notoriously poor.  Judging by your comment on priidikvaikla's answer, you're looking for officially produced standard object documentation, and as far as I know, none exists.

Comment: thx zombat. I'd make your comment as accepted answer if possbile

Comment: btw why don't ppl try to create one at facebook wiki?

Comment: non exists and that's a conincidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Developers wiki basically only documents the raw API. The official PHP library is a thin(-nish) wrapper around this API, and includes some minimal phpdoc documentation in its comments.

If you want to generate documentation for the library, you need a copy of [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) (and the CLI version of PHP installed). Then you can run:

```
./phpdoc -t /path/to/write/documentation -o HTML:default:default -d /path/to/facebook-platform/php/
```

or in Windows:

```
php.exe "C:\Path\To\phpdoc" -t C:\Path\For\Documentation -o HTML:default:default -d C:\Path\To\facebook-platform\php
```

to generate some local HTML documentation. But like I say, it's pretty minimal, and there's not much benefit over just reading the documentation inline with the code.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found what you are looking for. Check http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JS_API_T_FB.Facebook

If you scroll down, you can view the whole namespace.

It took a lot of digging to find this.

Comment: many thanks. This link will be very helpful when I need to write facebook connect apps

Answer (score 0):

Download the Official Facebook PHP Client Library package from http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PHP and if you open facebookapi_php5_restlib.php you can see the methods and properties.

Comment: come on... I need a class reference, on Web. Doesn't it completely suck to have no class reference on wiki and you will have to dig the methods & properties by looking at the php file?